# Why am seeing user icons instead of identicons in chat room?

Tags: support, chat, profile-picture

Recently I was chatting with other users in [HTML / CSS / WebDesign](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29074/) where I saw common user icon as a profile picture for three users, when I visited their profile, they were having random identicons, so are we tweaking the chatrooms or is this a bug?

Reference Image 1

[image]

Reference Image 2

[image]

Links to user profiles :

- [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4006585/)
- [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4044817/)
- [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4040504)

So inshort, identicons are showing up as user icons in the chatroom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to their chat profile (not their Stack Overflow profile), you should see something like this:

[image: screenshot of a user profile that says 'actual avatar is hidden']

The "why?" link leads to https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#avatar, which says

> If you are a new user with very little reputation, then instead of the avatar you usually have on Stack Overflow you may see the non-descript shape shown on the left. Because we have had issues with offensive avatars in the past, we hide new users' avatars until they have earned some reputation on Stack Overflow.

See my [answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239291/115866).

Comment: Sad, I didn't checked the users chat profile, but if users are not uploading any profile picture of their own, showing identicons shouldn't harm.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Gravatar doesn't tell you what TYPE of avatar you get back - if it's a custom or identicon. There is no way to tell the difference, hence the blanket blocking of all low-rep user's icons.